# Unable to apply changes on device on iOS real device

Tags: ios, nativescript

I run `tns run ios` error on my real device after I change a develop `.cert` and `.mobileprovision` file.
I delete old cert in my `keychain-access` and double click the `.cert` file and the `.mobileprovision` file,
and I even update cli and `tns-core-module` to latest version, but it's still not work.

Could anyone help me?

I use mac .
cli version is 5.3.1
xcode version is 10.1
My package.json is here:

```
"nativescript": {
    "id": "com.softbrain.discounteasy",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.2.1"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.3.1"
    }
  },
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "@danvick/ngx-translate-nativescript-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "nativescript-angular": "~7.1.0",
    "nativescript-clipboard": "^1.1.7",
    "nativescript-code-push": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-exit": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^1.3.5",
    "nativescript-hex-string": "0.0.4",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^6.1.2",
    "nativescript-localstorage": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-microsoft-appcenter": "^1.2.1",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^8.0.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
    "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.6",
    "nativescript-windowed-modal": "^5.0.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.3.1",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^5.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.4.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^7.1.4",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "^1.6.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.19.0",
    "tns-android": "^5.1.0",
    "tns-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.1"
  },
```

and the build log here:

```
nativescript-plugin-firebase: /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/.pluginfirebaseinfo not found, forcing prepare!
nativescript-plugin-firebase: running release build or change in environment detected, forcing prepare!
Detected short imports in your application. Please note that short imports are deprecated since NativeScript 5.2.0. More information can be found in this blogpost https://www.nativescript.org/blog/say-goodbye-to-short-imports-in-nativescript

In file /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/app/pages/tabs/home-page/home-page/home-page.component.ts line import * as application from 'application' is short import. Add tns-core-modules/ in front of the required/imported module.

In file /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/app/shared/pipes/image-cache.pipe.ts line import { ImageSource, fromResource } from 'image-source' is short import. Add tns-core-modules/ in front of the required/imported module.

In file /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/app/shared/pipes/image-cache.pipe.ts line import { Cache } from 'ui/image-cache' is short import. Add tns-core-modules/ in front of the required/imported module.

In file /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/app/shared/pipes/image-cache.pipe.ts line import { isFileOrResourcePath, isDataURI } from 'utils/utils' is short import. Add tns-core-modules/ in front of the required/imported module.

Hook skipped because either bundling or livesync is in progress.
Hook skipped because either bundling or livesync is in progress.
Preparing project...
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-angular for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-clipboard for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-code-push for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-feedback for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-hex-string for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-imagepicker for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-localstorage for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-microsoft-appcenter for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-plugin-firebase for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-theme-core for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-toast for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-windowed-modal for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-intl for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-appversion for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-zip for ios.
nativescript-permissions is not supported for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-permissions for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules-widgets for ios.
Installing pods...
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `ISMessages` from `https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/ISMessages.git`, commit `580ac8cab611e2f92ebdd62b2201f9dada36ccd4`
Downloading dependencies
Installing AppCenter (1.14.0)
Installing Firebase (5.16.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (5.5.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.2.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (5.2.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (3.7.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (3.3.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (5.5.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (5.5.0)
Installing ISMessages (1.2)
Installing Protobuf (3.7.0)
Installing QBImagePickerController (3.4.0)
Installing SSZipArchive (2.1.4)
Installing Toaster (2.0.4)
Installing nanopb (0.3.901)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `DiscountEasyUI.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 7 dependencies from the Podfile and 15 total pods installed.
Project successfully prepared (iOS)
Configure firebase
Android not installed, skipping CodePush hook.
Building project...
Xcode build...
2019-04-06 09:39:21.580 xcodebuild[1297:29067]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from df1b668dc0b68ae30113d5198979559ab1938293 was NULL
warning: Swift 3 mode has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Xcode. Please migrate "Toaster" to Swift 4.2 using "Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…" in the Edit menu. (in target 'Toaster')
warning: Swift 3 mode has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Xcode. Please migrate "Toaster" to Swift 4.2 using "Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…" in the Edit menu. (in target 'Toaster')
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastCenter.swift:36:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let `default` = ToastCenter()
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastWindow.swift:24:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let shared = ToastWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastCenter.swift:36:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let `default` = ToastCenter()
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastWindow.swift:24:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let shared = ToastWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastWindow.swift:24:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let shared = ToastWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastCenter.swift:36:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let `default` = ToastCenter()
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastCenter.swift:36:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let `default` = ToastCenter()
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastWindow.swift:24:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let shared = ToastWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastCenter.swift:36:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let `default` = ToastCenter()
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastWindow.swift:24:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let shared = ToastWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastWindow.swift:24:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let shared = ToastWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Toaster/Sources/ToastCenter.swift:36:19: warning: static declarations are implicitly 'final'; use 'public' instead of 'open'
  open static let `default` = ToastCenter()
  ~~~~            ^
  public
/Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/ISMessages/ISMessages/Classes/ISMessages.m:198:1: warning: conflicting return type in
      implementation of 'accessibilityPerformEscape': 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') vs 'bool' [-Wmismatched-return-types]
- (bool)accessibilityPerformEscape {
^  ~~~~
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/ISMessages/ISMessages-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:276:1: note: 
      previous definition is here
- (BOOL)accessibilityPerformEscape NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
^  ~~~~
1 warning generated.
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
Xcode build...
2019-04-06 09:40:04.685 xcodebuild[3913:36112] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/qx/nqzfs3217731kb43q_pcpvfh0000gn/T/DiscountEasyUI_2019-04-06_09-40-04.685.xcdistributionlogs'.
Exported DiscountEasyUI to: /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos
Project successfully built.
Installing on device df1b668dc0b68ae30113d5198979559ab1938293...
Unable to apply changes on device: df1b668dc0b68ae30113d5198979559ab1938293. Error is: Failed to install /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/DiscountEasyUI.ipa on device with identifier df1b668dc0b68ae30113d5198979559ab1938293. Error is: Could not install application.
```

Comment: I resolved it here. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55555851/unable-to-apply-changes-on-device-install-fail-even-in-simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55555851/unable-to-apply-changes-on-device-install-fail-even-in-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

Is the device included in that provisioning profile? Drag the profile to the TextEdit application and look for:

`<key>ProvisionedDevices</key>`

Is `df1b668dc0b68ae30113d5198979559ab1938293` listed after that? If not, in the Apple Developer Portal, update the provisioning profile to include your device. Then, try again with the updated profile.

The only other reason I can think of for an app not to install is if the device doesn't meet the minimum requirements; if the device's iOS version is less the the app's deployment minimum, for example.

To see more information about the installation failure, open the Console application (***not the Terminal***), connect your unlocked phone to the computer, and then select the device in the Console application. Try to install the app again.

In the "Search" box at the top of the Console window, enter the name of your application and press enter to filter the log based on that.

[image: Search box]

You'll see a lot of text with details about the installation. It will look something like this, but should indicate an error somewhere:

```
default 23:04:32.280735 -0400   streaming_zip_conduit   com.mycompany.SuperApp:5:1:1:1:Beginning installation for file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/SuperApp.app/ with options {
    AllowInstallLocalProvisioned = 1;
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.mycompany.SuperApp";
    DisableDeltaTransfer = 1;
    InstallDeltaTypeKey = InstallDeltaTypeSparseIPAFiles;
    IsUserInitiated = 1;
    PackageType = Developer;
}
default 23:04:32.288006 -0400   lsd com.mycompany.SuperApp:5:1:1:1:Ininstall file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/SuperApp.app/ with options {
    AllowInstallLocalProvisioned = 1;
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.mycompany.SuperApp";
    DisableDeltaTransfer = 1;
    InstallDeltaTypeKey = InstallDeltaTypeSparseIPAFiles;
    IsUserInitiated = 1;
    PackageType = Developer;
}
default 23:04:32.289279 -0400   lsd com.mycompany.SuperApp:5:1:1:1:Ininstall file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/SuperApp.app/ with options {
    AllowInstallLocalProvisioned = 1;
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.mycompany.SuperApp";
    DisableDeltaTransfer = 1;
    InstallDeltaTypeKey = InstallDeltaTypeSparseIPAFiles;
    IsUserInitiated = 1;
    PackageType = Developer;
}
default 23:04:32.292304 -0400   installd    0x16b15f000 -[MIClientConnection _doInstallationForURL:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/SuperApp.app" type Developer (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by lsd (pid 31819)
default 23:04:32.306147 -0400   assertiond  Request to create termination assertion <BKSTerminationAssertionCreateEvent: 0x105ec9a00; Identifier: 29899-552C42A1-9731-49B7-B96B-41A0B2D360AB; Name: FBSApplicationTerminationAssertion; Target BundleID: com.mycompany.SuperApp; Efficacy: Unconditional> from client <BKClientHandle: 0x105f0da40; installd:29899; connections: 1>
default 23:04:32.309880 -0400   SpringBoard termination assertion efficacy for com.mycompany.SuperApp (app not found) changed to 3
default 23:04:32.310150 -0400   installd    Acquired termination assertion for event <BKSTerminationAssertionCreateEvent: 0x10a802170; Identifier: 29899-552C42A1-9731-49B7-B96B-41A0B2D360AB; Name: FBSApplicationTerminationAssertion; Target BundleID: com.mycompany.SuperApp; Efficacy: Unconditional>
default 23:04:32.321511 -0400   installd    0x16b15f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.mycompany.SuperApp; Version=1, ShortVersion=1.0>
default 23:04:32.321804 -0400   installd    com.mycompany.SuperApp:7:5:1:1:Start : Install (New)
default 23:04:32.822905 -0400   installd    0x16b15f000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:waitForDeletion:withError:]: Made container live for com.mycompany.SuperApp at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E18E5DFA-A7E2-4B20-AA88-571213D25CA4
default 23:04:32.827238 -0400   installd    0x16b15f000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:waitForDeletion:withError:]: Made container live for com.mycompany.SuperApp at /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/53C45EA1-44C3-4AAE-BD6E-72EE3F82B8BA
default 23:04:32.859543 -0400   installd    com.mycompany.SuperApp:7:5:2:1:Success (End) : Install (New)
default 23:04:32.859738 -0400   installd    0x16b15f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful for (Developer:com.mycompany.SuperApp); Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.01s, Verifying: 0.46s; Overall: 0.57s
```

There should be more clues there.

Comment: Yet, I'm sure it contains this device.

Comment: ok, one other thing you can try, Open the `Console` application, connect your unlocked phone to the computer (meaning connect it by wire, even if you're normally using wireless install), and select the device in the `Console` application. Try to install it again. Do you see any more information about the install failure?

Comment: And my device version is iOS 12.1

Comment: I use wire connect to iphone all the time, and I try to use mac terminal to run `tns run ios`, but it still not work. And I can't find other error informations now.

Comment: The `Console` application has a xcodebuild error this: `Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2881 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert`

Comment: that's ok, that's unrelated. Updating my answer with more things to look at. one sec.

Comment: I find an error: `No installable items found at /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.FlZEhJ/extracted/Payload` on my device logs in `Console` application.

Comment: does this app install in the simulator, or does that also fail?

Comment: Install in simulator still fail. Error infomation is same as this.

Comment: Ah. Ok, I'd start with trying to figure out that then. If it worked in the Simulator but not on a device I'd expect that it was a cert or provProf issue again.

My suggestion is that you create a new SO question about your nativescript project not even installing in the simulator, since this really isn't a device install issue. It sounds like your built nativescript app bundle is not correct for some reason.

I'd also fix those warnings in the original build log. That way, at least you'll know they're not part of the problem.