# Unable to apply changes on device. Install fail even in simulator

Tags: ios, nativescript

My project run `tns run ios --emulator` fail after I update latest version and change cert and provision file.
I looks up Console appliation when I run `tns run ios` on my real device, it show `0x16d55f000 -[MIInstaller _discoverInstallablesWithError:]: 610: No installable items found at /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.FlZEhJ/extracted/Payload`.
And before one week, it's build ok.
The error is:

```
Unable to apply changes on device: 1BADCC4A-CC22-4434-991F-B589BB647826. Error is: Command xcrun with arguments simctl install 1BADCC4A-CC22-4434-991F-B589BB647826 /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/projects/DiscountEasyUI/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DiscountEasyUI.app failed with exit code 1. Error output:
 An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
This app could not be installed at this time.
Failed to chmod /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1BADCC4A-CC22-4434-991F-B589BB647826/data/Bundle/Application/72BE1C1C-8129-4BB4-A3FA-467F5BA38E09/DiscountEasyUI.app/discounteasy : No such file or directory
Failed to chmod /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1BADCC4A-CC22-4434-991F-B589BB647826/data/Bundle/Application/72BE1C1C-8129-4BB4-A3FA-467F5BA38E09/DiscountEasyUI.app/discounteasy : No such file or directory
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=4):
        Failed to chmod /Users/softbraintechnologylimited/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1BADCC4A-CC22-4434-991F-B589BB647826/data/Bundle/Application/72BE1C1C-8129-4BB4-A3FA-467F5BA38E09/DiscountEasyUI.app/discounteasy : No such file or directory
```

I use mac .
and my cli version is 5.3.1 .
xcode version is 10.1

package.json:

```
"nativescript": {
    "id": "com.softbrain.discounteasy",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.2.1"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.3.1"
    }
  },
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "@danvick/ngx-translate-nativescript-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "nativescript-angular": "~7.1.0",
    "nativescript-clipboard": "^1.1.7",
    "nativescript-code-push": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-exit": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^1.3.5",
    "nativescript-hex-string": "0.0.4",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^6.1.2",
    "nativescript-localstorage": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-microsoft-appcenter": "^1.2.1",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^8.0.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
    "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.6",
    "nativescript-windowed-modal": "^5.0.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.3.1",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^5.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.4.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^7.1.4",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "^1.6.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.19.0",
    "tns-android": "^5.1.0",
    "tns-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.1"
  },
```

could anyone help me?

Comment: Repost: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7112

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem.
I had changed `CFBundleExecutable` from `App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist`, and then this problem appears.
When I changed it back to `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}`, it works.